# Using regionprops in MATLAB to detect shapes only in part of the picture

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I have video frames with elliptical objects in them. I'm trying to detect the main ellipse using regionprops and it works just fine. 
However, since I want to speed up the process, I want regionprops to only look for those ellipses in a certain area of the image. I can crop the images each frame, to only have the relevant area left, but I would rather have regionprops look only in specified areas.

Is such an option possible?

Comment: Why do you not want to crop the image (and by "crop", I assume you mean just passing a subarray of the image to `regionprops`.)

Answer (score 0):

Regioprops uses label matrix provided by bwlabel(bw_image) or just logical(grayscale_image) if you suppose that there is only object in the image. To make regionprops process only a part of image you should set irrelevant part of the label matrix to zero.